# spread operator with Babel on IE11

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I would like use **spread operator** transpiled with **Babel** on IE11, but this don't work :

```
const $navigationItemSubmenu = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]');

[...$navigationItemSubmenu].forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => showProduct(item) );
});
```

This work on all browsers, but not IE. I've not error :/ !

I use :

```
babel-preset-es2015
babel-preset-stage-2
```

Anyone have idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: The problem might rather be that `querySelectorAll` doesn't return an *iterable* collection in IE. Also, [`...` is not an operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508?s=3|2.6385#37152508).

Comment: What does it transpile to?

Comment: the result after transpilation is `[].concat(_toConsumableArray($navigationItem)).forEach(function(item){`

Comment: This issue may help https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/934

Comment: Thank you ! babel polyfill work nice :)