# Content not rendering on IE 11 (v-for)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I inherited some vue code with the company I work for and I don't have a lot of experience with vue so excuse any ignorance. I have a v-for that renders on all browsers except IE (we're contractually obligated to support it...)

Here is a basic example of the code:

```
<div v-if="!isLoading && hasData" class="gms-cards gms-cards--alt">
  <div
   class="gms-card gms-card--secondary"
   v-for="item in filteredOffers"
   :key="item.id"
  >
    <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
  </div>
</div>


filteredOffers() {
  const activeCategories = _.map(_.filter(this.catagories, ['selected', true]), 'items')
  return new Set([].concat(...activeCategories))
},

Here is a portion of this.catagories stringified

[{"items":[{"id":"1513","image":"http://images-cell.jpg","title":"Fruit platter in Hotel","shortDescription":"Pre order a fruit platter to your room.<br />\r\nAdd booking number for your stay in the next step."},{"id":"1512","image":"http://images-Sparkling.jpg","title":"Sparkling wine in Hotel","shortDescription":"Pre order a bottle of sparkling wine and root vegetable chips to your room.<br />\r\nAdd booking number for your stay in the next step."}]
```

The title shows on chrome and firefox but on IE 11 it acts as if the data isn't going through. I get no errors in the console.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#browser_compatibility

Comment: So it seems you need to run this through Babel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812954/spread-operator-with-babel-on-ie11